# advice on how to create this code more clearly

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style

```
$( function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 } );
```

-> datepickerload

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date());
 $( "#datepicker" ).change(function () {
      socket.send($( "#datepicker" ).val())

  })

});
```

->datepicker default value setting , datepicker on changed some event

To create the three work more succinctly, overlooking the advice to integrate into one

Comment: 1. You don't need two separate document ready handlers. 2.jQuery lets you chain methods. 3. `$(this).val()` is clearer and more efficient than `$( "#datepicker" ).val()` (noting that `this` only makes sense inside the event handler).

Comment: If you do not ready functionally separate, after all of the page is loaded,
Event features you know and get normally.
ex)
<Div id = "a"> (not loaded) -> $ ( "# a"). onclick (alert ( "hi")) -> fail

If the information that I know is wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand what you're saying in that comment. But I repeat: you don't need two separate document ready handlers. It is fine to put the three lines of code in your question into a single document ready handler. (If it doesn't work for you there must be some other problem from code not shown.)